# 4 intersecton points of 2 conic circles are always concyclic?

Tags: conic-sections

> Given 2 conic section of type
>
> $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
> have 4 intersection points. Are the points for sure concyclic?

If yes, does the proof come from the fact that I can create an infite amount of new conic section using the linear combination of them and there is for sure a value of lambda that will give me a circle?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

No. In geogebra varying coefficients you can easily find counterexamples. [image: false]

This has solutions

$(1,0),(\frac1{\sqrt{3}},\frac1{\sqrt{3}}),(-\frac1{\sqrt{3}},-\frac1{\sqrt{3}}),(\frac37,-\frac87).$

Which you can check are not concyclic: $(x-1/6)^2+(y+1/6)^2=13/18$ does not contain $(\frac37,-\frac87).$

Comment: how would i find the coefficients of the polynomials to disprove this?

Comment: or how can u disprove this in a formal way?

Comment: @NethanelBenzak: See edit.

Comment: This is a question on an exam. How did u calculate the conic section and know which circle to fit and know which points would disprove this?